# Errors creating and getting model

Tags: php, laravel, orm

This model is not behaving properly. It does not fill in its attributes, nor can I call `find()`, `get()`, or any kind of getter on it.

Here is it's create_matches_table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('matches', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('p1');
        $table->integer('p2');
        $table->integer('u1');
        $table->integer('u2');
        $table->string('p1_action')->nullable();
        $table->string('p2_action')->nullable();
        $table->bigInteger('clock')->unsigned();
        $table->smallinteger('round')->unsigned()->default('1');
        $table->integer('victor')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('murder');
        $table->integer('wager')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('notoriety')->nullable();
        $table->integer('stalemate')->default('0');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->datetime('finished_at')->nullable();
    });
}
```

Using `Match::create($data)` where `$data` is an array of attributes perfectly lining up with those required will not fill them in. The returned object never has a `clock` attribute as desired above.

I have begrudgingly circumnavigated these issues by using:

```
public static function setMatch($data)
{

    $match = new Match;
    $match->fill($data);
    $match->clock = time() + 6;
    $match->save();

    return $match;
}
```

Even in doing this, trying to get a particular record of this object by `$match = Match::find([$id])->first();` yields this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031 (SQL: select * from `matches`
>   where `matches`.`id` in (?)) in Connection.php line 729

```
at
> Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from `matches` where
> `matches`.`id` in (?)', array(), object(Closure)) in Connection.php
> line 685 at Connection->run('select * from `matches` where
> `matches`.`id` in (?)', array(), object(Closure)) in Connection.php
> line 349 at Connection->select('select * from `matches` where
> `matches`.`id` in (?)', array(), true) in Builder.php line 1610
```

I have tried hardcoding values, passing it as an array, and even just going for `Match::first()`, and all return this error.

All I need is for this to behave as a regular ol' model.

Comment: Are you configure your database settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not chain `first()` after `find()` since `find()` returns an object:

```
Match::find($id);
```

Also, make sure `$fillable` has correct attributes and [define a mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) for `clock` attribute to make `create()` work:

```
public function setClockAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['clock'] = time() + 6;
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `$fillable`, I had tried `$guarded = ['id', 'created_at']`. After removing this (and fixing the query builder chain), it worked just fine. It was the `$guarded` that caused this error though.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code need to update like:

`Match::find([$id])->first();`

To

`Match::find($id);`

Or

`Match::where('id',$id)->first();`

Hope this work for you!